# css pseudo class stops working when in different tag

Tags: css, list, checkbox, tags, hide

I'm stomped on this one and I don't even know which terms to search for...(at least the ones I tried isn't turning up anything close to what I'm looking for)

What I'm trying to do is use CSS to expand/collapse a list using a checkbox (no javascript, manager's request). The problem I'm running into is that it only works if it's under the same tag as the list. example below

This works:

```
--head--
<style type="text/css">
  .hide:checked ~ #list
  {
    visibility: collapse;
   }
</style>

--body--
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="hide" checked="checked"> Hide
    <table id="list">
      <tr>
       <td>test</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <ol >
           <li>item 1</li>
           <li>item 2</li>
           <li>item 3</li>
        </ol>
       </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

But this doesn't

```
--head--
<style type="text/css">
  .hide:checked ~ #list
  {
    visibility: collapse;
   }
</style>

--body--
  <input type="checkbox" class="hide" checked="checked"> Hide
  <div>
    <table id="list">
      <tr>
       <td>test</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <ol >
           <li>item 1</li>
           <li>item 2</li>
           <li>item 3</li>
        </ol>
       </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

and I have no idea why (I'm not really that well trained in CSS btw)

NOTE: the difference is the placement of this code if you can't find what's different between those blocks of code

```
<input type="checkbox" class="hide" checked="checked"> Hide
```

any help would be great, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `~` operator in CSS means "followed by". However, the checkbox isn't followed by the table, there's only a div. Sure, the table is there, but it's deeper inside the DOM tree.

Solution: either take the table out of the div, or adjust the CSS.

```css
.hide:checked ~ div > #list
```

Comment: Right, the tilde looks for siblings, the original non-working code has a 'nephew'

Comment: ooohhh, Thank You so much,  the last time I had read about DOM was 8 years ago in school lol